# How to store image larger than 6mb in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, blob

i want to upload image upto 6mb in mysql. now i am using longblob to store image in mysql. but it can only store images less than 500kb. Here the code is working but cant't upload large image. any one help me out .. thank you ...

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, photo) values (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement statement = db.con.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, firstName);
statement.setString(2, lastName);

if (inputStream != null) {
    statement.setBlob(3, inputStream);
}
int row = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

choose one of the following blob types in your database to store large size images

**Binary**: Fixed size up to 8,000 bytes.

**VarBinary(n):** Variable size up to 8,000 bytes (n specifies the max size).

**VarBinary(max):** Variable size, limit of 2 GB.**

if it is server side error check this link
[click here](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7017666)

Comment: how to use these types in mysql code . it returns error

Comment: only change the data type in your database. the error may be due to the capacity of the data type in your database and the size of data inserted to it

Comment: is that your error? why don't you copy the stack trace and show me

Comment: ERROR: Packet for query is too large (4216666 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.

Comment: Edit the following file:
Linux: /etc/my.cnf
Windows: c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server version\my.ini

Find the [mysqld] section
Add this entry: max_allowed_packet = 1024M
Restart the MySQL server